# Looking for Efficient Encoding Permutations with Boolean Variables

Tags: satisfiability

I'm exploring the use of SAT solvers to find a permutation of the numbers 1, 2, and 3, subject to specific constraints. Initially, I considered employing nine variables: $x_{1,1}, x_{1,2}, \dots, x_{3,3}$, where $x_{i,j}$ is true if the number $i$ is placed in position $j$ in the permutation.

However, since there are only $3! = 6$ possible permutations, it seems excessive to use nine variables. I'm contemplating using just three boolean variables, $y_1, y_2, y_3$. My idea is to map each permutation to a unique combination of true or false values of these $y_i$'s. But I'm finding it challenging to formulate the constraints under this scheme.

Could there be a more efficient encoding strategy that strikes a balance between the number of variables and their expressive power? I'm seeking a method that simplifies the representation of permutations and constraints in a SAT solver context.

Comment: If you're looking for non-repeating permutations, your three numbers will only ever have two degrees of freedom - Once you've picked your first and second numbers, your third is chosen for you - it has to be the number you haven't picked yet. So, you only really need to encode which number was chosen first, and which was chosen second.

If you can choose *with* repetition, obviously this won't work - you really will need to encode all three numbers for each variable,  because you'll always have three choices at each selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In isolation, the obvious answer is to enumerate all 6 permutations and check which ones satisfy the conditions.

Without more context, this is not answerable.  There are many ways to represent a permutation of 3 elements.  We can't tell you which is best, because that depends on the rest of your model.

Here are some candidate options to consider:

- A one-hot encoding of which of the 6 permutations has been chosen.  This requires 6 boolean variables.
- A binary encoding of which of the 6 permutations has been chosen.  This requires $\lceil \lg 6 \rceil = 3$ boolean variables.
- For each pair $i,j$, a boolean variable indicating whether $\pi(i)<\pi(j)$.  This requires 6 boolean variables.